# How to read mapping and response files from disk

Tags: java, mocking, wiremock

I deploy `WireMock` as a single WAR to my server. I followed the provided [sample-war project](https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/tree/master/sample-war) to make my WAR works. That was very useful, so thanks for this example.

The only one problem with my app is that WireMock reads mapping and configuration files from inside the WAR.
The path of these files is configurable via the `WireMockFileSourceRoot` context-param in the `web.xml` file but it only works if the path points to a directory which locates in the WAR.

I would like to keep mapping and response files in a separate folder on the disk.

I have checked the source code and as I can see WireMock use `ServletContextFileSource` class to read mapping files from the servlet context. This class extends `AbstractFileSource`.

I have found a good candidate `SingleRootFileSource` which also extend the same abstract class and it seems for me that this class can read mapping files from any directory from the disk BUT I have no idea how to set up WireMock to use this class instead of the default.

Could you please put me to the right direction?

Comment: Not sure why WireMock would require the mappings and configuration files to be "...inside the WAR". I've heard good things about WireMock but you have a choice of API simulation/mocking tools out there that don't have such requirement. (disclaimer: I'm involved with one such tool)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to convert files read by `SingleRootFileSource` to `StubMappings`. Eg:

```
SingleRootFileSource stubsFolder = new SingleRootFileSource("my/path/to/jsons/with/recorded/stubs")
stubsFolder.listFilesRecursively().each { TextFile stubFile ->
StubMapping mapping = StubMapping.buildFrom(stubFile.readContentsAsString());
...
```

Then you need to register them in Wiremock server. There is couple of ways how it can be done. Both wiremock server and client can register stubs. Dunno how you run tests, but if you need different stubs per test case, you possibly would have to register stubs use client (using `com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.stubFor`). In case you decide to use `stubFor` you have to introduce simple adapter that converts `StubMapping` to `MappingBuilder`, as `stubFor` is taking only `MappingBuilder` as parameter. Sample adapter:

```
public class MappingBuilderAdapter implements MappingBuilder {
    StubMapping stubMapping;

    @Override
    public StubMapping build() {
        return this.stubMapping;
    }
    
    ...
```

Client has to be connected to server before invoking `stubFor`. Checkout `configureFor` method to connect from wiremock client, described in [Configuring WireMock using the Java client]: http://wiremock.org/docs/running-standalone/